# Replace pushViewController with segue in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, segue, mkannotation

I created app with own MKAnnotation. I have another ViewController and I try send data by segue.
Now, I have Navigation Controller and working code like this

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let annotationView:MyAnnotation = view.annotation as! MyAnnotation
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let detailStoryboard = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "stationDetails") as! DetailViewController
    detailStoryboard.stationTitleText = (annotationView.title)!
    detailStoryboard.bikeRacksText = (annotationView.bike_racks)!
    detailStoryboard.bikesText = (annotationView.bikes)!
    detailStoryboard.freeRacksText = (annotationView.free_racks)!
    detailStoryboard.distanceText = (annotationView.distance)!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailStoryboard, animated: true)
}
```

But, I want replace Navigation Controller by segue. 
I created segue with identifier "pinTouched", and replace last line in my code by

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "pinTouched", sender: nil)
```

My perform func look like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "pinTouched")
    {
        var detailScreen = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    }
}
```

I tried in few ways send this data in this function, but I have only white screen.
How can I fix it?

Thanks for answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill the data

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "pinTouched", sender:view.annotation)
}
```

then inside `prepare(for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "pinTouched")
    {
         let detailStoryboard = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
         let annotationView = sender as! MyAnnotation 
         detailStoryboard.stationTitleText = (annotationView.title)!
         detailStoryboard.bikeRacksText = (annotationView.bike_racks)!
         detailStoryboard.bikesText = (annotationView.bikes)!
         detailStoryboard.freeRacksText = (annotationView.free_racks)!
         detailStoryboard.distanceText = (annotationView.distance)!
    }
}
```